# can i use postgresql in android phone?

Tags: android, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to develop Android application and I want to use database in my application. I know that I can use sqllite in Android, but is it possible to use Postgres instead of sqllite?

I am talking about installing db in phone and not using remote DB server.

Is it possible?

Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 23):

PostgreSQL is now available for Termux on Andriod

Install Termux from the Play Store and run it.

To install PostgreSQL:

```
$ pkg install postgresql
```

To start it first create your folder you want to store the data in and then init te folder:

```
$ mkdir -p $PREFIX/var/lib/postgresql
$ initdb $PREFIX/var/lib/postgresql
```

To start the server:

```
$ pg_ctl -D $PREFIX/var/lib/postgresql start
```

To stop the server:

```
$ pg_ctl -D $PREFIX/var/lib/postgresql stop
```

Create a user to allow you to connect form an App:

```
$ createuser --superuser --pwprompt yourUserName
```

Create your database:

```
$ createdb mydb
```

Open your database

```
$ psql mydb
```

You will now see the promt:

```
mydb=#
```

PostgreSQL is up and running now.

Comment: Just curious, Is this method can be accessed from outside phone environment? Let assume, I will make my phone as DB-Server and access it from PC (as client).

Comment: This doesn't seem feasible for a customer-facing app. Particularly, one with many users. Especially, given that the instructions say, `You can obtain Termux builds from F-Droid. Do not install it from Google Play.`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, [now you can](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Postgresql), using Termux (a terminal emulator and Linux environment for Android and Chromebook).

Answer (score -1):

There is no PostgreSQL port for Android.

PostgreSQL cannot be compiled for Android. And it really would make very little sense: PostgreSQL is particularly suited to large databases and multi-user access. Also, it is unlikely that you need PostGIS's functionality on an Android device. There are multiple database / spatial data apps out there; or develop your own from available toolkits.

Comment: I need postgres because my mapping application in web uses postgres. I don't want to use  sqllite in mobile version and postgres in web. I need to collect data in mobile and then upload the data to web when there is internet connection. I need some spatial field in my mobile app which has to be compatible to postgres and sqllite doesn't have that.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the instructions mentioned above, I installed Termux from the web site then run `apt install postgresql`
After that I get error:

```
Unable to locate package postgresql
```

[image]